# Find $∠ADC$ given $A,D$ on circle with diameter $BC$ and $∠BAO = 50°$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

If $BC$ is a diameter of the circle and $∠BAO = 50°$. Then find the value of $∠ADC$.

[image]

This stumped me a little, I think there is a rule that mentions something about the center of the circle and it's relation to angles on the circumfrence, but I'm not sure, could someone help me point out the laws that would help to solve this problem? (Do not give me the solution, since I want to approach this myself)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle

Comment: But frankly, you don't really *need* this. The problem can be done just using the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$ and a few basic things about angles.

Comment: The question isn't well formulated. There's no restriction on the location of `D` and it could be anywhere in the cicle. Therefore, the are an infinite number of values of ADC that would meet the criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hints

Mark the congruent line segments in the figure (a circle has a **constant** radius) to observe that:

> $$\measuredangle ABC = \measuredangle BAO$$

Then, try to use the fact that the measures of the angles in the same segment of a circle are equal (the measures of two angles at the circumference subtended by the same arc are equal):

> $$\measuredangle ABC = \measuredangle ADC$$

Comment: ABC = ADC? I don't think so.

Comment: @TheImpaler Why don't you think so? The measures of the angles are clearly equal.

Comment: Because AD is not a diameter.

Answer (score 0):

See $ \angle  OAB = \angle OBA  = 50^\circ$ (why?)

$\angle AOC = 100^\circ  $ (why?)

Now see angle subtended in the centre is double the angle subtended at any other point on the circle. Join AC. Now $ \angle AOC = 2\angle ADC$

> $\angle ADC= 50^\circ $

Comment: You have a small mistake. It should be $\angle AOC = 2 \angle ADC$ instead of $2\angle AOC = \angle ADC$

Comment: Oh I didn't realised that. Thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Since $AO=OB$, $\angle A =\angle B=50^\circ $. Thus $\angle O =100^\circ $. Since $\angle ADC= \frac1 2 \angle AOC$,

> $\angle ADC= 50^\circ $.

Comment: AO = AB? There's no indication of this in the question.

Comment: @TheImpaler Happy?